# how to download the image in vuejs but i am getting the respone as this i am using the following below code

Tags: vue.js

�PNG

IHDR{{cM�PLTE�$���� %�~��y�$��� ������z{��������X[�����FI��������������`b�14����������pr�<?�!��#� ���Ŏ���7XP������JJJ###rrr���@@@D
)       �b222_]]���m�Z��ZIDATh�śk[�:�{I�jN�E����rTtAPq����ɥMR�1�v1���L&�d�x�����ֿlt]��6.���߽�rK�U�5� l�q�&%����Q�~e��V��p�0&���8�F���|v�S������0�S��?�ݺnͨ�{(Q3h\�)o®T����A��)��Mд�J3��ͮ�C{rJ�:݋٭Z� ��?�͸^<��n ��;�����%��kн*�n�%#�;9����Agh��I�(�L�|�UJ��´����%?�{�={vMP���*ߡE�N����P�GA͒ݺx�d6ߓ�)}>s�?�9&�fW��y2{�ȅ��<�;�U�6%�ǜ����)�n�Ո#堫�W!j�`�e'��p���ɦ`��&�?|����ʩN�_&�_��9�F�~ʍ�.�� ���h36�ߏ`�@�v������,ӔM�Ǡ"  E�ؕ��?T(m����A��J���˟���l
���q�U��.ş�-�FP�y�Ϯ&h6��y����s;ܒ-t{�S������ɕfǦrl�Dq[��������T쓢�k��ê����]�,[��*`�_��V�����H�5�k����������l�c��Ȯ�#�h^(ɞ��gV����g^��hK����>����x96{��ño�ښ/Ŧ����
0��NL)��gL��U�v�W9�=�W���h��c;xoe�k�Ҵ�]�
�Yp}`��K�gH+��0�l�-j���S�:����tzg�f�F�^Fi6�㩵Qv���/d;���u��V�]>R�?�=q�N��̟�����l�*�z�V��l�KO��`G��iǱ_���=�l�Wү`ǲ�0ӓ�0ܚ���lo��t�������o�g��D|�����������*�~ٲ��c�<�s������"�-�m�6;'4ϝ�݇]��MQ��vl�n�����`���ߙ��?�w�lT�a#�Zx�"p����f�ς�K
�n��lD�����$�]����wf�-����1��T������7kN�M�̳�>�vՓ�n�F9�S�f�-�;��d�:[����w#��if�`�ŗN���c�C+o��
ވ͔N����y�p���P�6k�P݀�����[»N�O25k�-V]���y���!�l��<�1ױ���|k�^�����5l^����wAvW�vДkϩ^��G:)��сM���\�G^��d�^�F�h�j;(kC��o��$�`�����=�b�.���5��J��Z���l�4�0W��l���|8�&(u�yl����gϡ?��=�v2|U�V|�_�5��u��H27�����[��T����߽�m�(�a��,��-?�K�Íj�פ��N�1\N�����[Ҥ�^.���6�t����t!��<mW�Ֆ����o��{�n�ޒ�gM�}*ܟ��%h_����\h�Z���98�||����Zz.�1}h�X��?��s(��_}�v�s(<?��8-�f�ew��n�S���4�w`�20:��e�o�q&��Gi6y��L��rlU|��+ޛ)�V�a��-povl�2���<��u2ȇ[���Yn~���3��?ٰ9/���r7ol]����q���:s6��K(M�W�@�q��NƔ��. �Yq����G�ܐ��0aQ��'�+&�,Ռ��W�4](���<��D��r"�
���c
�Sż\��\��ձ1�pU��r��E>2q7kHװ1�O�dh�|d)��G?@fpc�ތ��[�a������)YH?��?��{*q2G)>��d�ψ�7��{/IB�P�?�Ƀ����J�7��yU���l>^O$���lB��;�j�w��}���$)#ח?�}  -���]�a9�]����}�Rݿ��XR���\R��`Z���|��P���.��u�Ɛ���IEND�B`�

```js
   Nova.request().get('API',{responseType: 'blob'})
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log("sa", response)
                        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]))
                        const link = document.createElement('a')
                        link.href = url
                        link.setAttribute('download', file_name)
                        document.body.appendChild(link)
                        link.click()
```

Comment: That's the binary contents of a png file. Please show a [mre] with the code you are using and what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Could you share the code you're using? not the response you're getting.

Comment: Oscar David  - the above code only i am using for download

Comment: you probably need to set the type of the blob

Comment: i already set the responseType as 'blob'

Comment: you need to set the type of the blob itself though to tell the browser it's a png

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.download = file_name;

                        let blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'image/png'});

                        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                        link.click();

                        URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
```

i have change the code like this but i am still getting as photo source file is missing whether i need  to change in backend